# Nested subquery in sqlite3 for updating table record

Tags: sql, sqlite, nested, sql-update, subquery

I have a sqlite database having following schema

```
Models:Table  --This table maintain all models name and their current stock
model_id   IDENTITY      NOT NULL,
model_name VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
created_on DATE          DEFAULT (date('NOW') ),
have_now   INT           DEFAULT 0

check_in:Table  --This table registers all models that is eneted into store
check_in_id IDENTITY,
on_date     DATE,
quantity    INT,
model_id    INT,
notes       VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT [Details not found.]

check_out : Table  --This table register all models that goes out of the store
check_out_id IDENTITY,
on_date      DATE,
model_id     INT,
quantity     INT,
notes        VARCHAR (200) DEFAULT [Details not found.]
```

whenever any item goes out or comes in have_now is updated to reflect quanity available.
To update i am using this query

```
update models set have_now = 
( select (ins.sumOfIns - outs.sumOfOuts) balance
FROM
( select
    model_id,
    sum(quantity) sumOfIns
    FROM check_in
    where model_id = 6
    GROUP BY model_id
) ins
LEFT JOIN
(select 
    model_id, 
    sum(quantity) sumOfOuts
    FROM check_out
    where model_id = 6
    GROUP BY model_id
) outs

ON ins.model_id = outs.model_id )
where models.model_id = 6
```

this works well for updating a singel model.
However i need a query which will update all the models depending upon their check in 
and check out .
I can achieve this programatically in the application 
by iterating thorugh model_id one by one and feeding that  to 
above query , get result and update that in model table.

But i am sure it can also be achieved using query only.
Basically what i need to know how to iterate model table
get its current model id and use that id in above query 
as subquery and use result to update model have_now field

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: As far as I know, SQLite does not support `FROM` in an `UPDATE` statement (https://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).  That makes it really hard to understand your question.

Comment: SQLITE does support FROM in the update as i  have used this in above mentioned code snippet.

Comment: Being not able to understand my question, I have a query which work perfectly but it uses a conditional statement. What i want to achieve is use above query to update all rows of the model table, according to model_id from models table

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try an `update` with `from` using SQLite.

Comment: Maybe you do not have a record having model_d=6 in the models table.

Comment: I ran this query in sqliteBrowser again and yet no error.